# Ember 2.11.X How to get the Input value of and component through the action handler

Tags: ember.js

Problem: I want to transfer the changed value from the input-field component to the action, but i recieve only the initially value.

The controller holds the variable width with an initially of 100, but should update after the value changed in the input field.

```
        <form {{action 'resizePanel' value on="submit"}} class="form-inline waves-effect waves-light" style="width:50px">
                 {{input-field type="text" value=width classNames="form-control" style="width:50px; color:white"}}
        </form>
```

sdf

Comment: can you share implementation of the component input-field? if you experience such a problem, most probably it is not using two-way-binding to the width value (which is a good thing in my opinion), but it must also provide an action in order to be notified about potential updates of underlying input element. a twiddle illustrating your case might be excellent, by the way.

Comment: Hey, ok there is the twiddle:
https://ember-twiddle.com/50da8205ff23cba80337e3ef3cc6c3a1?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.input-helper.hbs

Comment: See my answer below please, I have modified your twiddle to illustrate you alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `input-helper` component extends `Ember.TextField` then you don't need to send an argument to action helper.

[Twiddle-Link](https://ember-twiddle.com/df8f3f7f4c81d27e4d10afa93629cd89?openFiles=components.input-helper.js%2Ctemplates.components.input-helper.hbs)

input-helper.js component file

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.TextField.extend({
});
```

application.hbs, you can remove width argument from action helper

```
<form {{action 'setWidth' on='submit'}}>
{{input-helper type="text" value=width class="form-control" style="width:50px; color:black"}}
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the explanation why your provided [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/50da8205ff23cba80337e3ef3cc6c3a1?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.input-helper.hbs) does not work. You have created your very own component with input tag. You made attribute binding with value; but you are not doing anything to bind the value field of your component to html input element's value attribute.

Take a look at the [TextField](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/7819409b7b6559e9fc0300a29e66a16356fb67a7/packages/ember-glimmer/lib/components/text_field.js) code of Ember. It is using a mixin called [TextSupport](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/ca66d1908295861aa7861fb64deee4dc7b3316df/packages/ember-views/lib/mixins/text_support.js). If you look at the source code of it, you can see that Ember itself is handling Html DOM Events. So it is very natural that two-way binding to `width` defined in `application.js` is not working; because the value of the `value` property in your `input-helper` component is not being synchronized with the `value` html attribute via handling DOM events. In other words the change in `value` attribute is not being reflected to `value` property in your component.

Here is what you can do?

- Just use built-in `input` helper of Ember like [this](https://ember-twiddle.com/40a276757e4a9995b3405ec7e65efe5f?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C) and it will simply work.
- If you intent to use your very own component, then just handle the DOM events like Ember. Even a very [simplified version](https://ember-twiddle.com/f0032191ca765abeb7176548a266a239?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C) of event handling taken from Ember will do the job. Even you can use Ember's TextSupport mixin I have mentioned above.

Comment: OP requested to have style attribute in input element. that is the reason he is not preferring Ember inbuilt input helper.

Comment: Ooops i have missed that part; thanks for pointing out. Then he can use Ember's TextSupport mixin as I suggested in the answer I guess.

Comment: Sure. OP mentioned it in twiddle but not mentioned it in question.

Comment: Thank you for your approch, i going to use this time of technic definitely in one place, thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think you can just pass `width` in the `action` helper:

```
<form {{action 'resizePanel' width on="submit"}} class="form-inline waves-effect waves-light" style="width:50px">
  {{input-field type="text" value=width classNames="form-control" style="width:50px; color:white"}}
</form>
```

Comment: Hey Chris, no if i use width like value i got only the last value, in my example above 100, but i changed the input value from 100 to 200. but i dont know why the width param is not updated.

Comment: Ahh, I'd recommend updating your question to have `width` as I pointed out in my answer then. As @alptugd also suggested, I'd like to see more details about how `input-field` is implemented.

Comment: Hey, ok there is the twiddle:
https://ember-twiddle.com/50da8205ff23cba80337e3ef3cc6c3a1?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.input-helper.hbs